# insert razor code in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net MVC with EF6, I did paging by Skip and Take method like this in my controller

```
    private const int PageSize = 6;
  public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue, int page = 1)
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        if (SearchBy == "Name")
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
            ViewBag.PageSize = PageSize;

            int p = page - 1;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
            ViewBag.PageSize = PageSize;

            List<MyTable> SupList = new List<MyTable>();
            SupList = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).ToList();
            var subCategoryToReturn = SupList.Select(S => new { Name = S.Name });
            ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(((double)subCategoryToReturn.Count()) / PageSize);
            var temp =subCategoryToReturn.ToList().Skip(p * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
            return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
       else
        return Json(new EmptyResult(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

how can I add paging links in JavaScript?
I tried to add this Razor code in ajax to display page number, but it is impossible to add Razor in ajax

```
 @for(int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalPages; i++) { <
                a href = "@Url.Action("
                GetSearchingData ","
                MyControllerName ", new { page = i } )" > @i < /a>
              }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Search").keydown(function() {
      var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
      var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
      //SearchData is the div name to append the result of ajax to html
      var SetData = $("#SearchData");
      SetData.html("");
      $.ajax({
          //some code
          url: "/MyControllerName/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
          success: function(result) {
            //Receive the filtering data from controller and show it for user
            $.each(result, function(index, value) {
              var Data = '<div class="col-sm-3" ><div class="card"><canvas id="header-blur"></canvas><div class="avatar"></div><div class="content"> <p>' +
                value.Name + '</p></div></div></div>';
              SetData.append(Data);
            });
            //here is my question how to add this Razor code to ajax ?
            SetData.append(
              @for(int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalPages; i++) { <
                a href = "@Url.Action("
                GetSearchingData ","
                MyControllerName ", new { page = i } )" > @i < /a>
              }
            );
          }
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Create a partial view, then load that with ajax.

Comment: Suggest you use a plugin such as [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList). And as a side note, to not use `.ToList()` in you query - that downloads all records and then performs `.Skip()` and `.Take()`, instead of downloading just the records you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor formatting can get very tricky.  In this case, you'll have to try and keep all of this on one line.  Give it a try:

```
@for(int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalPages; i++)
{
    @:"<a href = "@Url.Action("GetSearchingData ","MyControllerName ", new { page = i } )"> @i </a>";
}
```

edit:  If it spits out encoded HTML, you can also do it this way:

```
@Html.Raw("<a href = \"" + Url.Action("GetSearchingData ","MyControllerName ", new { page = i } ) + "\"> @i </a>")
```

Comment: Thanks Jason second one is added without error in VS but it disabled the search process